# Changing Picture Box, BackgroundImage from an user control using another user control

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have some buttons from User Control(UserCtrl2) and want to dynamically change UserCtrl1,PictureBox BackgroundImage. From my code below, UserCtrl2 PictureBox BackgroundImage property did changed but winform is still showing the previous BackgroundImage.

I have tried the following methods,

1. me.refresh in UserCtrl1, still nothing happen.
2. Not sure how to implement {Get and Set} or dispose function.

Thanks in advance for any advise or reference.

Here is my code for UserCtrl1:

```
Public Class UserCtrl1
    Public Sub UserCtrl1_Task(LEDno As UShort, LEDState As Boolean)
        Select Case LEDno
            Case 0 : Exit Sub
            Case 1
                If LEDState Then
                    PicBox_A.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("Blue_ON")
                Else
                    PicBox_A.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("Blue_OFF")
                End If
        End Select
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here is my Code for UserCtrl2:

```
Public Class UserCtrl2
    Private ButtonClick(4) As Boolean

    Private Sub Btn_A_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn_A.Click
        Dim InputControl = New UserCtrl1

        If Not ButtonClick(0) Then
            ButtonClick(0) = True
            Btn_A.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("Switch1_ON")
            InputControl.UserCtrl1_Task(1, True)
        Else
            ButtonClick(0) = False
            Btn_A.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("Switch1_OFF")
            InputControl.UserCtrl1_Task(1, False)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You cannot do this: `Dim InputControl = New UserCtrl1`: you create a **new** object, different from the existing `UserCtrl1`. You could raise an event when `Btn_A` is clicked, using a custom `EventArgs` class to pass those values (`(1, True)`, `(1, false)`) to the subscribers of the event. The Parent Form can subscribe to the public Event of `UserCtrl2` and call the public method of `UserCtrl1` (`UserCtrl1_Task()`) using the properties of the Event's `EventArgs` as the arguments.

Comment: The proper way to handle this is that all communication between every parent/child pair is done via properties, methods and events of that parent and child. If a user control contains a `PictureBox` then ONLY that user control should be changing properties of that `PictureBox`. That can be done inside a property or method of the user control. The form can then set that property or call that method. The other user control would raise an event when the `Button` is clicked to tell the form to do it. Stop complicating things by thinking of anything other than simple pairs of parents and children.

Comment: Just as the `Button` raises an event to tell `UserCtrl2` to do something, so `UserCtrl2` raises an event to tell the form to do something. The form should then be getting the appropriate `Image` and passing it into `UserCtrl1`. Just as `UserCtrl1` sets a property of the `PictureBox`, so the form sets a property of `UserCtrl1`. Simple: event, event, property, property. Also, if you haven't already, name those two user controls something sensible. Names like those are NEVER good. The controls serve a role and their names should indicate that, just like `TextBox`, `Label` or `Button` do.